# How to get chapter numbers to work in sections with memoir pagestyle{headings} and using babel?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, babel

I have a very strange behavior which I have managed to get boil downed into this minimal example. It's probably a bug report for either memoir or babel developers (where should that be sent?) but I thought I should ask here if anyone can help me to get this working. The problem can be seen in page five of the generated document:

[image: ?? in header]

I was expecting "Regarding chapter 1" but got "Regarding chapter ??". If I removed the babel package it seems to work... But I need it. Is there other solutions?

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\pagestyle{headings} 
\chapter{Lorem} 
\label{one}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Comments} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\section{Regarding chapter~\ref{one}}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I realize that the heading of the question probably is quite long. Feel free to make it better if you see an easy way! (I don't...)

Comment: Did you compile your document twice?

Comment: This isn't specific to `memoir`; it happens also with the `book` class, so it's mainly a `babel` issue.

Comment: That's interesting. So babel is the problem then. I thought the headings pagestyle was a memoir thing so I didn't bother trying the book class. Is there a workaround though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the console log, you will find that the error reported is that the label `ONE` is undefined.  Yet your label is `one`. This shows that the problem is that the label is being converted with `\MakeUppercase` or its equivalent before the reference is being resolved.  A partial solution is to wrap the reference in `\lowercase`, or make the label all uppercase. I've gone for the latter in the following example.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\pagestyle{headings} 
\chapter{Lorem} 
\label{ONE} % make label uppercase
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Comments} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\section{Regarding chapter~\ref{ONE}}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by the way of using uppercase heading, it affects the reference. An easy workaround would using capital letter labels for cross-references where you know they will be used in capitalized text. You will see it if you write `\label{ONE}` and later

```
\section{Regarding chapter~\ref{ONE}}
```

Surely it can be repaired. Though I recommend not using all caps text but for example `\scshape` instead.